# Using headers and libraries, when porting to Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm a newbie in cross-platforming programming with Qt 5. Now I'm trying to compile project for Android. Please, help me with several questions:

- I got a problem with net function `ntohs()`; as I considered because of using headers from host platform (Ubuntu 64-bit), not target. What should I do to use target headers?
- I must link several libraries (in gcc flags: `-lX11 -lm -ldl -lpthread`). What should I do to use it in Android?

If you have some links referred to above questions, please share.
Thanks!

Comment: The file search shows several `pthread.h` files, e.g. `android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-x86/usr/include/pthread.h`. In general, you run mc (Midnight Commander) [or Far Manager for Windows/Wine] and search for what you need. If something is not there, you search google and include the code. You have asked a very generic question, I'd suggest you find an Android NDK/JNI tutorial and reproduce what you can, and if something does not work, ask a particular question here. Start with an empty project and add your functionality, step by step if possible.